# Localization of Settings.bundle defaultvalues

Tags: iphone, localization, settings.bundle

How can I have a localized default values in the Settings bundle?  I encounter this problem for regionally sensitive defaults.

Consider an option in the settings bundle to indicate whether to show distances in miles or kilometers.  The default settings for en_US and en_GB is 'miles, and km for everywhere else.

Does the SDK provide a settings for that?  Or should I just add a third option: 'Infer metric system, miles, kms'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `Settings.bundle` string values can be localized.  Not defaults.